# LASToMultiPoint_3d creating empty files?

Tags: arcpy, lidar, las

Trying to use the arcgis python command
**LAStoMultipoint_3d** as seen [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000009m000000).

I'm running the code snippet against one of my LAS files.  It creates a `.shp, sbx, shp.xml, shx and dbf` file.  However, the files are empty.

The code is as follows:

```
#import script modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
env.workspace = "D:\myFolder\"

arcpy.LASToMultipoint_3d("D:/myFolder/myFile.las",
                         "D:/myFolder/Output" , 1.5)

print 'done'
```

The code executes and creates empty files.  I have tried this with a half-dozen different files varying in size and complexity.

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution is to use lastools.org arcgis toolbox which you can use in your python code. This has a tool called las2shp which will do the job.

Does the LAStoMultipoint3d work just as a tool? if it does then we can try to work out why it doesn't work in python. It also maybe that the output needs to be a fc and not a directory -so "D:/myFolder/Output_MultiZ.shp"

best,